# Difference between "хороший" and "xорошо"?

Tags: значения, разница

Both mean *good* but Хорошо is defined as the *short neuter singular of хоро́ший*.

AFAIK it is possible to use any of them when for example answering "Good!" or is there any practical difference?

Comment: Consider, for instance, "bad" and "badly".

Comment: Хорошо means well, not good.  It's an adverb. I have never heard a native speaker use Хороший as an answer.  Always Хорошо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When expressing general sense of goodness, satisfaction, delight, approval only **хорошо** is correct.

This is an adverb and not adjective, therefore short form doesn't apply to it as it's an attribute of adjectives. **Хорошо** in this case is the only form.

Adverbs denote in particular a state: **темно, светло, холодно, тепло, жарко, ладно, жалко, страшно, видно, слышно, больно** likewise **хорошо** and **плохо**

Short form of the adjective **хороший**<sup>*masc*</sup> is not **хорошо** but **хорош**. **Хорошо** is a short form of the adjective **хорошее**<sup>*neut*</sup>, but it's not the same as the adverb **хорошо**.

Answer (score -2):

Например, хороший кофе! А когда выпил, то тебе хорошо